# Access HTML <embed> content

Tags: javascript, html, embed

Is it possible to access the content of an embedded HTML-Document via javascript? Preferably the window  object.
(I have to pass a variable to a function inside the embed.)

Comment: If you can load it via JS, then you can access it via JS :)

Comment: @Anas Really? How? I tried embed.contentWindow etc. but it is undefined :/ Or is there another way to load the embed than embed.src = 'blah.html'; ?

Comment: I will post the answer down there

Comment: Why are you using `<embed>` instead of `<iframe>` in the first place?

Comment: thx @Quentin. Its an old project and I remember I had a reason for that, but I dont see any need for using embeds right now. Havent thought of this, solved my problem.